# Best approach for struct polymorphism in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a simple 2d vector object. It will have x and y components, and length, cross product, etc. methods. The thing is, I want to have the structure to have many possible types (char, int, float, double, etc.). I was wondering what would be the best choice, design wise, to interact with the object? Here's what I'm currently considering:

**1. Have the user pass the vector object to specialized functions, like:**

```
Vector2Dt_Dot(Vec2Dt* vector1, Vec2Dt* vector2);
```

where 't' is the type of the vector. However, the problem with this approach is that it disallows different types from interacting with each other, so I couldn't say calculate the dot product of a float vector2d and a double vector2d. A second approach, and what I'm leaning towards:

**2. Have the user pass the vector object(s) as void pointers, along with their types, like:**

```
Vector2D_Dot(void* vector1, unsigned vector1_type, void* vector2, unsigned vector2_type);
```

obviously this approach is more compact API-wise and also solves the above problem, but at the cost of a few extra parameters and type safety.

There may be other solutions that I'm not aware of, however these are the ones I'm currently considering. What do you feel is the best approach to this?

Comment: @WhozCraig the question is tagged `c`, not `c++`

Comment: Don't use the `void *` alternative; there are too many ways you can make mistakes that the compiler won't catch (because any pointer type can be converted to a `void *`, in C or C++).  At one time, this question (briefly) had a C++ tag and for a longer time use C++ reference type notation. If C++ is relevant, consider a `vector<vector<yourtype> >`.

Comment: @johnathan leffler: Yeah, that was my mistake. I switch between C and C++ often. I would definitely use a vector-like interface if it was an option in C.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you can do is to use polymorphic objects. Define the structures like this:

```
#define INT_TYPE 0
#define DOUBLE_TYPE 1
//more type constants

typedef struct Vector2D {
    int type;
} Vector2D;

typedef struct Vector2D_int {
    Vector2D super;
    int x, y;
} Vector2D_int;

typedef struct Vector2D_double {
    Vector2D super;
    double x, y;
} Vector2D_double;

//more typed vector structures
```

Then you can write your functions to accept `Vector2D` pointers, inspect their respective type fields and cast them down to the appropriate typed variant to access the payload data.

```
double Vector2D_length(const Vector2D* vector) {
    if(vector->type == TYPE_INT) {
        const Vector2D_int* intVector = (Vector2D_int*)vector;
        return sqrt(intVector->x * intVector->x + intVector->y * intVector->y);
    }
    if(vector->type == TYPE_DOUBLE) {
        const Vector2D_double* doubleVector = (Vector2D_double*)vector;
        return sqrt(doubleVector->x * doubleVector->x + doubleVector->y * doubleVector->y);
    }
    //other cases follow
}
```

This is polymorphism coded by hand. All you need to ensure, is, that the `type` field is always set to the correct value (set once when a typed vector is created).

The advantage of this approach to your second idea, is that you do not have to pass around the type of the vectors in another variable which would make using your vectors tedious and error prone.

As an alternative, you can define your `type` field to contain a pointer to a structure of function pointers. You would create one object of this function pointer structure per typed Vector type you define, and use it to lookup which function to use with the given vector. This approach would be very close to what C++ does under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variable argument list, its prototype is coded, for example, as:

```
int  xyz(int a, ...);
```

This style needs one defined parameter, in this example `a`, followed by any number of parameters whose data types can be determined at run time.

See the functions and objects: `va_list`; `va_start`; `va_args`; and `va_end`, for a complete description of how to process variable argument lists.

Hope this helps.  If questions about `va_list`, etc. please ask.

Answer (score 0):

What I actually went with was the following:

I created a base Vector2D class, with the following layout:

```
struct Vector2D_Base;
typedef struct Vector2D_Base{
    M_double (*Vector2D_Get_X)(struct Vector2D_Base* vec);
    M_double (*Vector2D_Get_Y)(struct Vector2D_Base* vec);
} Vector2D;
```

As you can see, this allows the generic vector functions to call these to get the derived classes' x and y values converted to doubles, which prevents the generic function from having to worry about difference between sizes of types like char and float. Then each derived class:

```
#define DEFINE_VECTOR2D(type, name)\
typedef struct{\
Vector2D_Base vec_base;\
type x, y;\
} Vector2D##name\
```