# C same structure different size

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, embedded, structure

My question is related to this one :
[c define arrays in struct with different sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956697/c-define-arrays-in-struct-with-different-sizes)

However, I do NOT want to use dynamic allocation (embedded target).

- Problem recap :

In **C**, I want to have two versions of the same structure, each one with a different size for its *static* arrays.
Both the structures will be used by the same functions through pointer parameter.

```
    typedef struct {
        short isLarge;         //set 0 at initialization
        short array[SIZE_A];
        //more arrays
    } doc_t;

    typedef struct {
        short isLarge;         //set 1 at initialization
        short array[SIZE_B];
        //more arrays
    } doc_large_t;

    void function( doc_t* document ) {
        if ( document->isLarge ) {
             //change document into doc_large_t* [1]
        } 
        //common code for both doc_t and doc_large_t
    }
```

- Questions :

(1) The above description needs a way to dynamically cast the pointer doc_t* pointer to doc_large_t* document [1]. Is that possible ? How ?

(2) An other solution i came with is to have a common header data part for both structure, including not only the isLarge flag, but also the pointers to the following static arrays. How ugly is that ?

(3) Also, do you have a good trick or workarround I could use ?

EDIT :

- More context :

My application is a path finding on an embedded MCU.

I have geometrical objects, like polygons. Polygons can describe simple rectangular obstacles, as well as more complex shapes (such as the accessible area).

Complex polygons can have a huge amount of vertices, but are in small quantity. Simple polygons are very common.

Both will use the same algorithms.
I know in advance which polygon will need more vertices.

What I am trying to do is to optimize working memory to make it fit into the MCU. (i.e. small shapes get small arrays; complex ones get large arrays)

Comment: You may want to check out something like this answer, it seems like you want to do something polymorphic with structs in c (being able to pass in different object types to the same function)

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18422235/7299836

Comment: For option 2 you should have matrix with enough rows to have arrays for all structs on your firmware, so UB is just behind the corner...

Comment: If `SIZE_A` and `SIZE_B` (as I suppose) are different, using [tag:c], you cannot "cast" values, you must code a conversion function. That means you must pre declare 2 struct for each case...

Comment: BTW It seems an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you want to achieve? Describe your objective and tell us all constrains.

Comment: *How* do you prefer to allocate these structures?  Doing what you want is relatively simple with a flexible array member, but that's not easy to use outside of dynamic allocation using `malloc()` *et al*.

Comment: @AndrewHenle On a MCU with limited resources, you should avoid dynamic allocation and prefer memory profiling.

Answer (score 2):

Idea similar to what you mentioned in your question already (pointers to arrays), but with only one single pointer:

```c
typedef struct
{
     short array[SIZE_B - SIZE_A];
     // more arrays alike...
} Extension;
typedef struct
{
    short array[SIZE_A];
    //more arrays (all the small ones!)
    Extension* extraData;
} doc_t;
```

If extraData is NULL, you have a small polygone, otherwise, you find the additional data in the struct referenced. Admitted, iterating over all values for large polygons gets a little nasty...

If you *can* use global arrays of predefined size for each object type (as Dominic Gibson proposed - a good proposition, by the way), you could spare the isLarge flag by replacing it with a function:

```c
int isLarge(void* ptr)
{
    return
        (uintptr_t)globalLargeArray <= (uintptr_t)ptr
        &&
        (uintptr_t)ptr < (uintptr_t)globalLargeArray + sizeof(globalLargeArray);
}
```

Of course, *all* polygons (in above case: the large ones at least) would have to live in this array to make it work. If you create at least one dynamically or otherwise elsewhere (stack, another global variable) - we are out...

Answer (score 1):

Create the arrays globally and use a pointer pointig to the big or small array.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to keep a single structure and for the different array sizes put them in an `union`. I don't know whether the following structure would make sense to your case.

```
    typedef struct {
        short isLarge;         //manually set to 0 or 1 after creating structure 
                               //and accordingly initialize the arrays in below union
        union my_varying_arrays {
            short array_A[SIZE_A];
            short array_B[SIZE_B];
        };
        //more arrays
    } doc_t;
```

If `isLarge` is `0`, set the value for `array_A` array and if `1` set the value for array `array_B`.

Comment: This would not be useful since this struct is as large as the larger one (right ?). What I am trying to do is memory optimization (see EDIT)

Comment: Hmm. If you are trying to allocate memory according to the input size then `unions` might not be the right approach since always allocate memory as per the larger element inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this is the data is `const` by using a `void *` to the specific array.
Then you just cast the `void *` to what you need it to be depending on the attributes in the structure.

It becomes more complicated when you need the structures in runtime.
Especially on embedded targets.

```
typedef struct {
    short size;
    void *array;
} doc_t;
```

Where `array` points to a memory block allocated by the memory manager.

You now have to decide whether to use C standard `malloc` or use some pooled memory system based on the largest block size.
An example would be [ChibiOS Memory pools](https://github.com/ChibiOS/ChibiOS/blob/577d33e5301ad23a3ef46811fcb20218d81e8f0e/os/common/oslib/src/chmempools.c). 
If you are allocating and freeing variable sized memory blocks at random you risk memory fragmentation.

If you allocate incrementally you don't have to worry about much about memory. Just create one large block and keep track of where you are. A bit like a stack.

Answer (score 0):

After the edit, I think the best thing you can do is to profile your needs defining max simple and complex polygons your target can manage and then declare a pool of simplex and common polygons, like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_COMPLEX 16
#define MAX_SIMPLE  16

uint16_t g_Simple_Poly_set[MAX_COMPLEX][SIZE_A];
uint16_t g_Complex_Poly_set[MAX_COMPLEX][SIZE_B];

uint16_t g_Simple_Poly_used = 0;
uint16_t g_Complex_Poly_used = 0;

struct poly
{
    bool     isLarge;
    uint16_t *vetexes;
};


bool create_poly_simple (struct poly *p)
{
    bool retVal = false; // default: not more space for poly

    if (g_Simple_Poly_used < MAX_SIMPLE)
    {
        p->isLarge = false;
        p->vetexes = &g_Simple_Poly_set[g_Simple_Poly_used][0];

        g_Simple_Poly_used++;

        retVal = true;
    }

    return retVal;
}

bool create_poly_compleX (struct poly *p)
{
    bool retVal = false; // default: not more space for poly

    if (g_Complex_Poly_used < MAX_COMPLEX)
    {
        p->isLarge = true;
        p->vetexes = &g_Complex_Poly_set[g_Complex_Poly_used][0];

        g_Complex_Poly_used++;

        retVal = true;
    }

    return retVal;
}

void your_stuff_with_poly ( struct poly *p)
{
    uint32_t poly_size = (p->isLarge == false) ? SIZE_A : SIZE_B;

    // your stuff with the correct size
}
```

This is a simple implementation designed for a static "instantiation" of structs. You can also enhance the code with a create/destroy function that trace which array into pool is free to be used.

Comment: The thing with embedded sys is to know the memory footprint. This seems appropriate. I'll go with this and report conclusions. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Your number 2 solution is the right idea.  It's unclear to me why you think that is ugly.  Maybe this beautiful implementation will change your mind.

You can implement single inheritance is C by placing the base structure as the first member of the inheriting structure.  Then inheriting objects can be referenced with a pointer to the base type.

```
typedef struct {
    short doc_type;
    short *array_ptr;
    // more array pointers
} doc_base_t;

typedef struct {
    doc_base_t base;         // base.doc_type set 0 at initialization
    short array[SIZE_A];     // base.array_ptr initialized to point here
    //more arrays
} doc_small_t;

typedef struct {
    doc_base_t base;         // base.doc_type set 1 at initialization
    short array[SIZE_B];     // base.array_ptr initialized to point here
    //more arrays
} doc_large_t;

void function( doc_base_t* document ) {
    if ( document->doc_type == 1) {
         // array size is large
    } else {
         // array size is small
    }

    //common code referencing arrays through doc_base_t->array_ptr
}
```

The `array_ptr` member in `doc_base_t` isn't necessary for the inheritance mechanism.  But I added that specifically for the "common code" portion of your function.  If `doc_base_t` didn't include the `array_ptr` then you could cast the generic `document` to either a`doc_small_t` or `doc_large_t` type based upon the `base_type` value.  But then you might need a different implementation for each inherited type.  By adding the `array_ptr` member to `doc_base_t` I suspect you could write a common implementation for all inherited types.

So you will statically declare all your instances of `doc_small_t` and `doc_large_t`.  And you'll initialize both the `base.doc_type` and `base.array_ptr` members when initializing each object.  Then you will cast both types of objects to doc_base_t before calling `function`.  (Or pass the address of the `base` member, which results in the same pointer value.)

**Updated example:**

```
static doc_small_t doc_small_instances[NUM_SMALL_INSTANCES];
static doc_large_t doc_large_instances[NUM_LARGE_INSTANCES];

// DocInit must be called once at startup to initialize all the instances.
void DocInit()
{
    int index;

    for (index = 0; index < NUM_SMALL_INSTANCES; index++)
    {
        doc_small_instances[index].base.doc_type = SMALL;
        doc_small_instances[index].base.array_ptr = doc_small_instances[index].array;
    }

    for (index = 0; index < NUM_LARGE_INSTANCES; index++)
    {
        doc_large_instances[index].base.doc_type = LARGE;
        doc_large_instances[index].base.array_ptr = doc_large_instances[index].array;
    }
}

// DocProcess processes one doc, large or small.
void DocProcess(doc_base_t *document)
{
    int index;
    short *array_member_ptr = document->array_ptr;

    int array_size = SMALL;
    if (document->doc_type == LARGE)
    {
        array_size = LARGE;
    }

    for (index = 0; index < array_size; index++)
    {
        // Application specific processing of *array_member_ptr goes here.

        array_member_ptr++;
    }
}

// ProcessAllDocs processes all large and small docs.
void ProcessAllDocs(void)
{
    int index;

    for (index = 0; index < NUM_SMALL_INSTANCES; index++)
    {
        DocProcess(&doc_small_instances[index].base);
    }

    for (index = 0; index < NUM_LARGE_INSTANCES; index++)
    {
        DocProcess(&doc_large_instances[index].base);
    }
}
```

Comment: These are completely different datatypes and this is completely wrong! A pointer is not an array and an array is not a pointer!

Comment: @Olaf I'm not sure what you mean.  My intention is that base.array_ptr be set to point to the first element of the array (for example: 
 `doc_instance_1.base.array_ptr = doc_instance_1.array;`).  Is it your position that a pointer cannot point to an array?

Comment: Hmm, I might have missunderstood what you intend. However, the UB stands: How are you going to get the actual type for the access, i.e. set the pointer to the array? I'm really curious how you do this without invoking UB by violating the effective type rule. Let this UB apart: how is that diffferent from casting the types without the pointer?

Comment: @Olaf I'm assuming the designer knows the number of small and large doc instances they require at design time.  They will write the code to statically allocate the appropriate number of instances.  And there will be an initialization routine that runs at startup to initialize the base members of each instance.  I've added more example code to my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: Did you even understand what the effective type rule is?? Please read the standard.

Comment: @Olaf I don't understand what you're concerned about.  I've tried to clarify for you twice but you just get more obscure with each comment.

Answer (score -2):

It's easy with `malloc()` or similar dynamic allocation methods.  Just use a flexible array member:

```
typedef struct {
    short isLarge;         //set 0 at initialization
     .
     .
     .
    short array[SIZE_A];
    short largeArray[];
} doc_t;
```

To allocate a "small structure":

```
doc_t *small = malloc( sizeof( *small ) );
small->isLarge = 0;
```

To allocate a "large structure":

```
doc_t *large = malloc( sizeof( *large ) + ( SIZE_B - SIZE_A ) * sizeof( large->largeArray[ 0 ] );
large->isLarge = 1;
```

Note that you must keep the `largeArray` element *last*, which means that the `array` element must be next-to-last for this to work.

Depending on how you do your own allocation, this may or may not be applicable.

(It's also a bit of a hack, since it depends on being able to access data in `largeArray` by using an index of `SIZE_A` or greater on `array`.  That's accessing an object outside its bounds...)

Comment: "However, I do NOT want to use dynamic allocation (embedded target).", Well, I would definilty use this answer, but the user do not want dynamic allocation

Comment: @kaldoran I understand the OP doesn't want to use dynamic allocation.  But he hasn't specified how he *is* allocating the structure(s).  Without that information, it's just about impossible to provide an answer precisely while using a flexible array member.

Comment: Indeed, this would be great but memory footprint would not be masterized anymore. I prefer an algorithm that cannot produce result, rather than crash because of full memory.

Comment: 1) There is no guarantee there is no padding between `array` and `largeArray`. 2) Accessing `largeArray` through a pointer initialised from `array` invokes undefined behaviour (out of bounds access). 3) Why not use a single FAM? 4) FAMs don't work with static or automatic objects.